# How to stop onload function even when refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day guys how can i stop the window.load function because my splashscreen always pops up everytime i refresh the page or turning to another page of my website

This is my code so far:

```
window.onload = function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    splashScreen();    
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

it always pops up . Can i do something like cookies so that the window.load will not function anymore or should i just destroy the function. Can anyone please i don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: it depends on when you want to show pop-up and when you won't?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve. But one suggestion, if you don't want to perform any action `onload` just remove it.

Comment: @AlivetoDie i don't understand sir. can you explain clearly

Comment: `Can i do something like cookies so that the window.load will not function anymore` - You basically answered your own question, because this is exactly what you can do. `sessionStorage` would probably do best for this kind of thing, where you set a session variable after you show the splash screen for the first time. On page load you check for this variable and only show the splash screen if the variable is not yet there.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to call the `splashScreen()` once, the first time you load the page, then you can save some value in localStorage of browser the first time you call the function and call the function only if the value is not present in localStorage. for example

```
window.onload = function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    if(localStorage.getItem('splash') === null){
       splashScreen(); 
       localStorage.setItem('splash', "true")
    }
}
```

That solves for refreshing the page.

But this will not allow the `splashScreen()` to be called if you open the page the next time after closing it, for this maybe you can save current time of calling the function in localStorage and then check if you want to call the function or not based on the time that was stored.

Comment: where did you get this ```getItem('splash')``` sir?

Comment: `getItem()` is a method to get values stored in localStorage using `setItem()`. you can get more information about these here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

The window.onload function will work every time you reload the window. If you want to show the splash screen on condition, you cannot use onload. The question is, when do you want to load the splash screen?